# How do I use ImageMagick in Android/Gradle without getting "Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, imagemagick

**Introduction**

I created a project in Android Studio.  This project was compiling and running flawlessly.  I tried to add ImageMagick from the following link:

> https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1416

**Files**

Here is an overview of my project's file structure.  I'll try to restrict it to the important files.

```
-AppRoot
  -build.gradle
  -settings.gradle
  -app
    -build.gradle
    -...
  -gradle-imagemagick-master
    -build.gradle
    -...
  -...
```

The root `settings.gradle` file looks like this:

```
include ':app'
include ':gradle-imagemagick-master'
```

The root `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The `build.gradle` file in the app folder looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apppackage.www.approot"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':gradle-imagemagick-master')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The `build.gradle` file in the gradle-imagemagick-master folder looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.4"
}

targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId 'com.eowise'
            artifactId 'gradle-imagemagick'
            version '0.5.2'
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = ''
    key = ''
    publications = ['MyPublication']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'gradle-imagemagick'
        licenses = ['MIT']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/eowise/gradle-imagemagick.git'
        version {
            name = '0.5.2'
            vcsTag = 'v0.5.2'
        }
    }
}
```

At this point it will clean, rebuild, and run without error on an android emulator.  I also have code that gets called as a result of a button press within my `MainActivity` that runs without error or crash.

**Step 1**

The problem comes when I try to use ImageMagick.  The first thing I try to do is add the following:

```
try
{
    Magick m = new Magick();
    m.convert("", Closure.IDENTITY);
    m.convert("", new PatternSet());
} catch (Exception ex) {}
```

This is within the function called as a result of the button press.  At this point I get

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Closure'
Cannot resolve symbol 'PatternSet'
```

as errors on the lines with `m.convert`.  At this point it will not build.  I then add the lines

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.util.PatternSet;
import groovy.lang.Closure;
```

to the top of my `MainActivity`.  This fails to build.  The errors it yields are:

```
Error:(18, 33) error: package org.gradle.api.tasks.util does not exist
Error:(19, 19) error: package groovy.lang does not exist
Error:(71, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable Closure
Error:(71, 22) error: cannot access GroovyObject
class file for groovy.lang.GroovyObject not found
Error:(72, 39) error: cannot find symbol class PatternSet
Error:(72, 22) error: cannot access DefaultTask
class file for org.gradle.api.DefaultTask not found
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**Step 2**

In order to get rid of the first two errors, I added

```
compile gradleApi()
compile localGroovy()
```

to the top of the dependencies closure in the `build.gradle` file in the app folder.  At this point I click `Build>Rebuild Project` and it says `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.  Then I click the Run button and it fails returning an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Users\<my user>\.gradle\caches\3.3\generated-gradle-jars\gradle-api-3.3.jar
    File2: C:\Users\<my user>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3\lib\groovy-all-2.4.7.jar
```

**Step 3**

From what I've read, usually this can be fixed or worked around by adding

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

to the `android` closure (within the `build.gradle` file in the app folder).  I've tried different combinations of these including using `pickFirst` rather than `exclude`.  If my `packagingOptions` closure does not contain the line `exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'` or `pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'` it continues to return the same error (`Duplicate files copied` above).

When I add

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

to my `android` closure, I am able to `Build>Rebuild Project` and I get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.  Then I click the Run button and I get a new error:

```
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

**Conclusion**

This is where I am currently stuck.  It seems that I shouldn't be adding the 2 `compile` lines in my app folder's `build.gradle` file because these lines are already in the gradle-imagemagick-master's `build.gradle` file.  I believe that this duplicate compiling is causing the duplicate license files error.  Is there another way that I can get the `import`s in my `MainActivity` to be recognized?

Comment: You seem to have runtime dependencies which should have been compile time dependencies.

Comment: How can I change them from run-time to compile-time?  Do you have any idea which dependencies they would be?  Would it be the groovy and gradle compile lines?

Comment: The gradle compile lines: Look for which package your first error comes from and set that one to compile (possibly also the second error, but usually it is wait and see OR read all the API docs)

Comment: Okay how can I set them to compile-time?